# button position changes at the run time

Tags: android, button, android-emulator

I am creating a application for android, wherein i am facing one strange kind of problem. The problem is that I've positioned the button in the center of the screen which is shown the same way in the GRAPHICAL LAYOUT of the file, but when i run the application in emulator the button is positioned more towards the right side and not centered. Can anyone point out the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#CCC"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel
        android:id="@+id/mytopPanel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="4dip"
        panel:animationDuration="1000"
        panel:closedHandle="@drawable/top_switcher_collapsed_background"
        panel:content="@+id/mypanelContent"
        panel:handle="@+id/mypanelHandle"
        panel:linearFlying="true"
        panel:openedHandle="@drawable/top_switcher_expanded_background"
        panel:position="top" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mypanelHandle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="33dip"
            android:paddingRight="50dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mypanelContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:hint="@string/editUserName" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:hint="@string/editUserPwd" >
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#323299"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="4dip"
                android:text="@string/drpDwnTxt"
                android:textColor="#eee"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:hint="@string/editNumber" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:hint="@string/editPwd" >
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerGateway"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/spinnerList"
        android:prompt="@string/spinnerPrompt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:onClick="save"
        android:text="@string/StrbtnSend" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This new layout file has done the job for me, just one small error was creating the trouble.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#CCC"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel
        android:id="@+id/mytopPanel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        panel:animationDuration="1000"
        panel:closedHandle="@drawable/top_switcher_collapsed_background"
        panel:content="@+id/mypanelContent"
        panel:handle="@+id/mypanelHandle"
        panel:linearFlying="true"
        panel:openedHandle="@drawable/top_switcher_expanded_background"
        panel:position="top" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mypanelHandle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="33dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mypanelContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:hint="@string/editUserName" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:hint="@string/editUserPwd" >
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#323299"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="4dip"
                android:text="@string/drpDwnTxt"
                android:textColor="#eee"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/mmWhoNo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnContact"
            android:hint="To: Type to search"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnContact"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/contacts_icon"
            android:textSize="18dp" >
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:hint="@string/editPwd" >
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerGateway"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/spinnerList"
        android:prompt="@string/spinnerPrompt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:text="@string/StrbtnSend" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAuthor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Designed By - Tapan Desai" />
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#CCC"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel
        android:id="@+id/mytopPanel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="4dip"
        panel:animationDuration="1000"
        panel:closedHandle="@drawable/top_switcher_collapsed_background"
        panel:content="@+id/mypanelContent"
        panel:handle="@+id/mypanelHandle"
        panel:linearFlying="true"
        panel:openedHandle="@drawable/top_switcher_expanded_background"
        panel:position="top" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mypanelHandle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="33dip"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mypanelContent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:hint="@string/editUserName" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:hint="@string/editUserPwd" >
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#323299"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="4dip"
                android:text="@string/drpDwnTxt"
                android:textColor="#eee"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:hint="@string/editNumber" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:hint="@string/editPwd" >
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerGateway"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/spinnerList"
        android:prompt="@string/spinnerPrompt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:onClick="save"
        android:text="@string/StrbtnSend" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

remove padding from the button xml and set gravity to center

```
layout_gravity="center"//can also set horizontal or vertical
```

and make sure you are not setting margin or padding in your java class where you are accessing it.

Comment: This is a ver low quality answer. Think about improving or deleting it.

Comment: @mindFreezer i made changes as per your suggestion but still no change. the layout is still the same